# C# Bulk Copy via OleDBDataReader from large excel file throwing out of memory exception

Tags: c#, excel, sqlbulkcopy

I have a large excel file(530K Rows with a lot of columns). Ends up being 247MB in .xlsb format. I am attempting to import to SQL Server using BulkCopy in C#, however I am having issues where the datareader ends up running out of memory before it even starts reading the file once I run the ExecuteReader() command.

```
string exlConnString = $"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={_filepath};Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;\"";
string sqlQuery = $"SELECT * FROM [{SheetName}]";
using OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(_connstring)) {    
   OleDbCommand exlCmd = new OleDbCommand(sqlQuery, conn)
   conn.Open();
   OleDbDataReader dr = exlcmd.ExecuteReader(); <---NEVER GETS PAST THIS LINE BEFORE RUNNING OUT OF MEMORY.
   SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(sqlConnString);
   bulkCopy.DestinationTable = TableName;
   while(dr.Read()) {
      bulkcopy.WriteToServer(dr);
   }
   dr.Close();
}
```

I am running in x86 mode because I was geting an error that the ACE Database was not installed on my local machine and corporate policy restrictions prevent me from downloading and installing the needed file to run it in x64 mode.

The code works perfectly fine when I test it on smaller files, but not when I test it on this bigger file, so it definitely is the filesize causing the issue.  Any suggestions or help would be appreciated. Doesn't make much sense that a bulk copy runs out of memory when it is meant for handling large sets of data, which also means that the filesize is going to be large as well...

And yes, I know I SHOULD be able to import this using OPENROWSET or OPENDATASOURCE in SQL Server but THAT is ALSO Turned off and they will not enable it, so this is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

So your problem is next.

When you try to `ExecuteReader` *DataReader attempt to read all data from your excel file to memory*. You could think about this, like a speciality working with excel through a OleDbProvider.

So my suggestion is to work with csv files instead of excel, because with csv file you have an ability to read and parse them line by line. For this aim i would recommend you to use [CSV helper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/)

Comment: I need it to handle both items, I alraedy have it working for CSV files.  Reason being is there are some datasets that will not map nicely to a CSV file and need to be in Excel format.  For instace in the one  I am trying to import, it has a detals field which contains comments by the people entering in the info, which pretty much will have all the delimters in the field itself which would screw up CSV formatting. Looks like  I need Open XML SDK which apparently is made for this.

Comment: I got your point! In this case, Open XML is probably an optimal choice.

Comment: @MattE export the CSV file with a custom delimitor e.g. ~ ^ |.

Answer (score 0):

Refer this code..
Here dtExcelData is datatable variable & da is OleDbDataAdapter variable.

```
 string excelConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={_filepath};Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=YES';";

                // Create Connection to Excel Workbook
                using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(excelConnectionString))
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    da = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * FROM [Sheet1$]", connection);    
                    da.Fill(dtExcelData);

                    //store data in sql server database table
                   // below connection string "conString" is I mention in app.config file.(sql server connection string to store data in sql server database)
                    string str = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conString"].ConnectionString;
                    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(str))
                    {
                        // Bulk Copy to SQL Server
                        using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(con))
                        { 
                            bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "TableName";
                            con.Open();
                            bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dtExcelData);
                            con.Close();
                        }
                    }                        
                    connection.Close();
                }
```

Mark it as a answer if it is useful to you. :)

Comment: I have already tried it with a data adapter and it has the same problem...runs out of memory

Comment: FYI, also when you use using there is no need to close the connection as it gets done automatically

Comment: How to do this inversely where source is SqlServer and target is excel?